# Cohomology of a group $G$ with coefficients in a vector space $M$

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be any group and $M$ a vector space over the field $F$. Let $B=\{x_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ a basis of $M$. If $M$ is a $G-$module, is it true that $H^{n}(G,M)\cong\bigoplus_{i\in I}H^{n}(G,M_{i})$, where $M_{i}=\langle x_{i} \rangle$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\langle x_i \rangle $? I can't think of any meaning of this that would make your desired statement true-- where did you get this idea?

Comment: No. Only if the action of $G$ on $M$ is trivial. Look up cohomology with twisted coefficients. There is a good book by ken brown.